# Equivalent of only_full_group_by for Postgres

Tags: mysql, laravel, postgresql

is there any equivalent MySQL's only_full_group_by for Postgres?

The reason is we had been hitting with this error `column of must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`. But this error did not occur with connecting with another database from the same Postgres server, it is only happening in one of the newly created database which has exact database structure and data with the one working fine.

So, wondering if there are any options that we can disable so that we are not hitting with this error.

Thanks.

Comment: No, PostgreSQL have no such extension. But you may use DISTINCT ON clause.

Comment: Any way to bypass it without changing the codes? The reason is, it can run successfully with my local and my production database. The problem only happens on staging (when I clone the database from my local). Plus it is kinda a legacy system, if possible, won't want to touch it, as this affected quite many parts of the code.

Comment: Are you saying your staging Postgresql server is a different version or has different configuration than your production Postgresql server? I think that's a huge red flag. The purpose of staging is to test out code so you are confident it'll work before deploying to production. If it isn't serving that purpose because it's a incompatible version or whatever, when why bother even having the staging environment?

Comment: @BillKarwin Hi, no staging and production is same postgresql server, with same version and same configurations (check by running `SHOW ALL`). The reason we setup the staging is to testing out a new module, but it is prompting error even for parts that are working on production and my local db.

Comment: Okay I can't imagine how the same query could get a different error if there are no differences in PostgreSQL version or config options. I seldom use PostgreSQL, so I'm not an expert. But I thought it was not possible to run that kind of logically invalid queries in PostgreSQL (only MySQL and SQLite permit it, no other brand of SQL database does, as far as I know).

Comment: I would recommend that you bite the bullet and fix your invalid queries that cause this error. They can only cause trouble.